# Dificuldade em transcrever um programa de console application para windows form(C#)

Tags: c#, .net

Estava aprendendo a usar split e no fim tinha esse codigo:

```
namespace String_Split
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string mensagem_completa;
            string palavra;
            string[] Apenas_palavras;
            Console.WriteLine("Apresente o texto a ser lido . . .");
            mensagem_completa = Console.ReadLine();

            Apenas_palavras = mensagem_completa.Split(' ', '.', ',');
            int tamanho = Apenas_palavras.Length;


            Console.ReadKey();

            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
            {
                palavra = Apenas_palavras[i];
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(palavra);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total de caracteres: " + mensagem_completa.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Total de palavras: {0}", tamanho);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
}
```

O programa executou sem problemas, tudo certinho.

Dai então pensei, por que não transforma-lo em um programa com windows form?
O resultado foi esse aqui:

```
namespace Split_em_Form
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public string[] texto_em_array;
        public string texto;
        public int tamanho_do_texto;
        public string palavra;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            texto = textBox1.Text;
            texto_em_array = texto.Split(' ', ',', '\n', '.');
            tamanho_do_texto = texto_em_array.Length;


            for (int i = 0; i < tamanho_do_texto; i++)
            {
                palavra = texto_em_array[i];
                label1.Text = "";
                label1.Text = palavra;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ao clicar no `button1` algo inesperado aconteceu, apenas o ultimo item da array apareceu no `label1`.
Ai minha duvida fica,por que isso aconteceu? Qual a diferença do código que escrevi na primeira vez para o segundo código e como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está jogando os valores no `label` e não concatenando-os, isso faz com que a cada *loop* `label.Text` tenha um valor diferente.

Sempre que você faz `Console.WriteLine()` uma nova linha é escrita. Já quando você faz `label.Text = "texto"`, você está fazendo com o que texto atual do `label` seja **substituído** por esse novo texto.

Para concatenar todos os valores do *array* no `label` ficaria assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho_do_texto; i++)
{
    palavra = texto_em_array[i];
    label1.Text += " - " + palavra;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Só como alternativa, ao invés de usar um `loop` para concatenar seus valores, você pode usar [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
label.Text = string.Join(", ", texto_em_array);
```

O primeiro parâmetro do método recebe o separador para os valores do array, o segundo é o array de `string` e o retorno será todos os valores do array separados por **,** (vírgula).

Answer (score 1):

Um *Label* só pode usar um texto de cada vez. Sempre que lhe é atribuído um valor, através de `label1.Text = palavra;`, o texto anterior é reposto pelo novo.

Apesar de utilizar o `Thread.Sleep(1000);` o *Label* só é actualizado visualmente(na tela) após o ciclo `for` ter terminado.

Para obter o efeito que pretende terá de chamar o método [Refresh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) após cada `label1.Text = palavra;`

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho_do_texto; i++)
{
    palavra = texto_em_array[i];
    label1.Text = palavra;
    Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Talvez uma melhor forma de apresentar as palavras seria usar uma *ListBox* em vez de um *Label*.

Coloque uma *ListBox* na sua *Window* e altere o código do `for` para:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho_do_texto; i++)
{
    palavra = texto_em_array[i];
    listBox1.Items.Add(palavra);
}
```